# How is bond length of C-O and C-N same?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, bond, molecules

[image: NCERT of class 11]

In NCERT and many other books it is given that bond length of $\ce{C-O}$ and $\ce{C-N}$ is same. But, how can it be possible as size of oxygen is smaller than that of nitrogen so bond length of $\ce{C-N}$ should have been more but it is not. similarly in $\ce{C-O}$ and $\ce{N-O}$, bond length of $\ce{N-O}$ should be smaller as nitrogen is smaller than carbon. but in books it is just reverse of that.

Bond order of all these molecules is same so bond length should depend on size of the bonding atoms but is not so in many cases. So what is the reason behind this.
is there any other factor that is responsible for such result?

Comment: this is not really true. it varies based on the bond in a given compound. Some examples are given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon%E2%80%93nitrogen_bond#:~:text=Similar%20to%20carbon%E2%80%93carbon%20bonds,triple%20bonds%20as%20in%20nitriles.

Comment: CO and NO bond lengths are not the same, and any source trying to state otherwise is most likely either trying to make an approximation or it's just textbook erratum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bond lengths given in your example tables are average bond lengths. That means, the actual bond length in given compound can be larger or smaller than the given value. Keep in mind that bond lengths are not just proportional to sizes of atoms involved making them. As pointed in the other answer, they are determine by other factors as well, which is a broad subject. One such factor is chemical structure of a compound. For example, let's compare chemical bonds in oxazole nucleus in oxazole derivatives with at least 2-substitutions (Ref.1-3):

[image: Oxazole Derivatives]

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\text{Bonds} & \text{Bond length in $\bf{I}$} & \text{Bond length in $\bf{II}$} & \text{Bond length in $\bf{III}$}  \\
\hline
\ce{O_{(1)}-C_{(2)}} & \pu{1.370 \mathring{A}} & \pu{1.356 \mathring{A}} & \pu{1.356 \mathring{A}} \\
\ce{C_{(2)}-N_{(3)}} & \pu{1.299 \mathring{A}} & \pu{1.294 \mathring{A}} & \pu{1.297 \mathring{A}} \\
\ce{N_{(3)}-C_{(4)}} & \pu{1.382 \mathring{A}} & \pu{1.410 \mathring{A}} & \pu{1.405 \mathring{A}} \\
\ce{C_{(4)}-C_{(5)}} & \pu{1.333 \mathring{A}} & \pu{1.310 \mathring{A}} & \pu{1.332 \mathring{A}} \\
\ce{C_{(5)}-O_{(1)}} & \pu{1.375 \mathring{A}} & \pu{1.399 \mathring{A}} & \pu{1.402 \mathring{A}} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

These data demonstrate how bond lengths in oxazole ring deffere by its substitutions and attached ring systems. Even two $\ce{C^\mathrm{sp^2}-O^\mathrm{sp^3}}$ bonds in the same ring gives two different values (*c.f.*, $\ce{O_{(1)}-C_{(2)}}$ and $\ce{C_{(5)}-O_{(1)}}$ values of each compound) because of substitution differences.

**References:**

1. Boon-Chuan Yip, Hoong-Kun Fun, Siang-Guan Teoh, Omar Bin Shawkataly, "Structure of 2-(1-naphthyl)-5-phenyl-1,3-oxazole ($\alpha$-NPO)," *Acta Cryst. C* **1993**, *C49*, 1532-1534 (https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108270193001192).
2. A. Albinati, M. G. Marcon, P. Traldi, P. Cavoli, "The structure of 2-amino-1,3-oxazole," *Acta Cryst. B* **1981**, *B37*, 2090-2092 (https://doi.org/10.1107/S0567740881008078).
3. P. Luger, G. Griss, R. Hurnaus, G. Trummlitz, "The $\alpha_2$-adrenoceptor agonists B-HT 920, B-HT 922, and B-HT 958, a comparative X-ray and molecular-mechanics study," *Acta Cryst. B* **1986**, *B42*, 478-490 (https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108768186097859).

Answer (score 4):

Bond length is not just proportional to atom size. Determine by other things too. One other determining factor of bond length is electronegativity. Bigger the difference in electronegativity the tighter the bond. I made up a table and stuff to illustrate this point but, as it so happens, the electronegativities didn't explain the data super well either.

I think it's good to keep in mind (with this and also the rest of chem) these are trends and predictors. If you want to get reasonably close to real life you gotta use schrodinger's equation.

(Here's a [table on atomic radii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radii_of_the_elements_%28data_page%29) which also show that there's many different ways to measure the radius of an atom. One might line up better than another.)